# Quantum Physics, Energy States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Which of the following transitions in a hydrogen atom **absorbs** a photon of the highest energy?

a.) $n=2\hspace{1cm}to\hspace{1cm}n=3$

b.) $n=3\hspace{1cm}to\hspace{1cm}n=2$

c.) $n=1\hspace{1cm}to\hspace{1cm}n=2$

d.) $n=5\hspace{1cm}to\hspace{1cm}n=6$

e.) $n=6\hspace{1cm}to\hspace{1cm}n=5$

f.) $n=2\hspace{1cm}to\hspace{1cm}n=1$

I know that **absorption** of energy can only take place when the elcetrons move from a lower state to a higher state. Initially then the only possible options are a, c, and d.

Using the formula

$E=\frac{-Rhc}{n^2}$

Thus the transition in an hydrogen atom from $n=1$ to $n=2$ absorbs the photon with the greatest energy.

Can someone else confirm this?

Comment: Just a slight correction, is the formula not $E=\frac{-Rhc}{n^2}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try easily what is the good answer by calculating the difference in energy between the two participating levels.

$E_{upper} - E_{lower} = -Rhc [\frac {1}{(n+1)^2} - \frac {1} {n^2}]$

$= Rhc [\frac {2n + 1}{n^4 + 2n^3 +n^2}]$

So, its obvious that the smaller n, the bigger $E_{upper} - E_{lower}$.

Comment: Yes I have calculated it. Hence my solution. I just want a confirmation, as I have peers who have differing opinions.